# Difficulty processing requests for ethsignedtypedata SAFE signatures in python to be able sign from independent python wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe

What is the proper format for authenticating these types of signature requests?
I'm using python and I can't seem to be able to produce the right signature with my wallet code. I tried encode_typed_data. I used other peoples json processing code still no success.

Thanks.

This is the signature request I'm dealing with coming from walletconnect:

(1677974610945129, 'eth_signTypedData', ['0x827d3e01191de9206ce85197d1e1f2b91ed7251d', '{"types":{"SafeTx":[{"type":"address","name":"to"},{"type":"uint256","name":"value"},{"type":"bytes","name":"data"},{"type":"uint8","name":"operation"},{"type":"uint256","name":"safeTxGas"},{"type":"uint256","name":"baseGas"},{"type":"uint256","name":"gasPrice"},{"type":"address","name":"gasToken"},{"type":"address","name":"refundReceiver"},{"type":"uint256","name":"nonce"}],"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}]},"domain":{"chainId":"137","verifyingContract":"0x9135a7832db16190475f409b649771532bb6fa7f"},"primaryType":"SafeTx","message":{"to":"0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174","value":"0","data":"0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000b3b1a1193a0b7b48b46efc3c86b614b152c257d500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240","operation":"0","safeTxGas":"0","baseGas":"0","gasPrice":"0","gasToken":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","refundReceiver":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","nonce":"0"}}'])